# Codeigniter formgenlib multiple forms under same controller

Tags: controller, codeigniter-2, multiple-forms

> That was a bug of the component being used.

I have to use multiple forms in a page.

My Problem:
I can not stop the code check the unsubmitted form with the other ?automaticly?.
*Errors are different. One’s error is not shown under other’s error list.

Here is my code to generate required forms using formgenlib under my controller.
By the way, If I click on the first button, "//do the stuff..." doesn’t work. But errors are shown.

```
$this->load->library('form');
                $login_form = new $this->form;
                $login_form
                    ->open()
                    ->col(240, 'left', 'left')
                    ->text()
                    ->col(170, 'left', 'left')
                    ->password()
                    ->col(100, 'left', 'right')
                    ->submit('', 'submit_login')
                    ->col(0)
                    ->validate();
                $data['login_form'] = $login_form->get();
                $this->load->view('overal_header', $data);
                $login_form->clear();
                $radio = array(
                    array('', ''),
                    array('', ''),
                );
                $register_form = new $this->form;
                $register_form
                    ->open()
                    ->fieldset()
                    ->text()
                    ->text()
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    ->submit('', 'submit_form');
                    if($this->input->post('submit_form'))
                    {
                        $register_form->validate();
                        if($register_form->valid)
                        {
                            //do the stuff here...
                        }
                    }
                $data['form'] = $register_form->get();
                $data['errors'] = $register_form->errors;
                $register_form->clear();
                $this->load->view('page_welcome', $data);
                $this->load->view('overal_footer');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would matter but the documentation shows using multiple forms a little differently.  Each form uses:

```
$this->form->text
```

instead of

```
$login_form->text
```

And doesn't differentiate between the two forms until the

```
$this->form->get()
```

So the call to clear would be

```
$this->form->clear()
```

Again, not sure this actually matters.  Maybe just something else to look at.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
This was what my code seems like when I started coding these forms.

We found out that, formgenlib's 1st version works without any problem with both codes.

But if you use the second version, we found out that, the second input with mail validation is not cleared with clear() function.

This might be a bug.

Comment: Did you try assigning names to the forms in the ->open call?